Two coupled $\text{LC}$ circuits Kirchhoff's law?
I clearly don't understand something about Kirchhoff's law. For instance, consider this circuit I want to quantise

My guess would be that the voltage loop equations should be
\begin{align}
    \text{Voltage loops: }&\begin{cases} 
      V_{C_1} + V_{L_1} = \frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1 \dot{I}_1 = 0 \\
      V_{C_2} + V_{L_2} = \frac{1}{C_2} Q_2 - L_2\dot{I}_4 = 0
   \end{cases}\notag\\
    \text{Current junctions: }&\begin{cases} 
        I_1 = I_2 + I_3 \\
        I_2 = I_4 + I_5. 
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{align}
And by using the current junction conditions we can write $I_1$ and  $I_4$ in terms of the capacitors charge:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1 (\dot{I}_2 + \dot{I}_3) = \frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1 (\ddot{Q}_g + \ddot{Q}_1) = 0\\
      \frac{1}{C_2} Q_2 + L_2(\dot{I}_2 - \dot{I}_5) = \frac{1}{C_2} Q_2 - L_2(\ddot{Q}_g - \ddot{Q}_2) = 0. 
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}
I assume we can eliminate $Q_g$ by charge conservation, $Q_g = Q_1 - Q_2$ (is this wrong?)
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1 (2\ddot{Q}_1 - \ddot{Q}_2) = 0\\
      \frac{1}{C_2} Q_2 + L_2(2\ddot{Q}_2 - \ddot{Q}_1) = 0.
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}
But those equations are off, they should be
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases} L_1 \ddot{Q_1} + 2C_g(\ddot{Q_1} -\ddot{Q_2}) + \frac{1}{C_1}Q_1 = 0\\
L_2 \ddot{Q_2}  +2C_g(\ddot{Q_2} -\ddot{Q_1}) + \frac{1}{C_2}Q_2= 0
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}

Can you apply Kirchhoff's laws like this?
I believe my reasoning is sound, but clearly, something is off if $C_g$ disappears!

hint: Charge conservation is not that the sum of charges on the three capacitors is constant but rather that the total charge in the whole circuit is a constant and is expressed by the two node conditions: $I_1=I_2+I_3$ and $I_2=I_4+I_5$. This is because the charges move in and out of the inductors and capacitors. How would you write down charge conservation for a pair a simple parallel LC resonator?

Previous question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/829671/174766

@hyportnex I see, so indeed $Q_g \neq Q_1 - Q_2$ (which dispels the worry of their sign). Then, if up to that point my reasoning is correct, my only way of removing $Q_g$ is by finding an equation for it and substituting. That would be, again by Kirchoff: $$L_2 \dot{I}_4 + \frac{Q_g}{C_g} - \frac{Q_1}{C_1} = 0.$$ So $$Q_g =  C_g(\frac{Q_1}{C_1} -L_2 \dot{I}4).$$ We substitute this into
$$\frac{Q{1}}{C_1}  + L_1 (\ddot{Q}_g + \ddot{Q}_1) = 0$$
and obtain $$\frac{Q_1}{C_1} + L_1(C_g(\frac{\ddot{Q}_1}{C_1} -L_2 \dddot{I}_4) + \ddot{Q}_1)$$ and similarly for $Q_2$. But this seems off too?

@hyportnex by off I mean that, if my last equation above was right too, then it would imply that $$L_1(  \frac{\ddot{Q_1}}{C_1} - L_2 \dddot{I}_4  ) = 2(\ddot{Q_1} - \ddot{Q_2}),$$ which I don't see how. Also, there has to be an easier way of doing this haha

With knowledge of the sign convention which you are using it is. not possible to answer your question with certainty.

@BobD Why do you keep closing this question?! It's not on the site and it is extremely relevant to many fields like superconducting circuits and quantum computing. The moderation of this site is becoming hyper restrictive and will impact it negatively. This is not the $n$-th question about a parabolic trajectory from a lazy high schooler, this is directly related to modern papers. Surely with enough imagination, every question is homework like or check my work type of question no??

@FriendlyLagrangian What do you mean I keep closing this question? This is the first time I've seen it and voted to close.  Anyway, I see the community is reviewing to reopen, so wait for their decision (I am not part of the review, so don't worry about me)

Hi FriendlyLagrangian. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the homework-and-exercises tag, and the Phys.SE policy for homework-like problems.

I found the answer to my question and I'm going to share it here for future learners, despite going against some haughty moderators' criteria, I think it constitutes a good question.

First of all, indeed $Q_g = Q_1 - Q_2$ or any similar reasoning is incorrect. However, the rest of the equations were well posed. Let me reproduce them here in addition with the final missing step:
I want to find the charge $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ of $C_1$ and $C_2$ to quantise the problem. My guess for the Kirchhoff voltage loops and current equations  would be
\begin{align}
    \text{Voltage loops: }&\begin{cases} 
      V_{C_1} + V_{L_1} = \frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1 \dot{I}_1 = 0 \\
      V_{C_2} + V_{L_2} = \frac{1}{C_2} Q_2 - L_2\dot{I}_4 = 0
   \end{cases}\notag\\
    \text{Current junctions: }&\begin{cases} 
        I_1 = I_2 + I_3 \\
        I_2 = I_4 + I_5. 
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{align}
And by using the current junction conditions we can write $I_1$ and  $I_4$ in terms of the capacitors charge:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1 (\dot{I}_2 + \dot{I}_3) = \frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1 (\ddot{Q}_g + \ddot{Q}_1) = 0\\
      \frac{1}{C_2} Q_2 + L_2(\dot{I}_2 - \dot{I}_5) = \frac{1}{C_2} Q_2 - L_2(\ddot{Q}_g - \ddot{Q}_2) = 0. 
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}
Now, I want to eliminate $Q_g$ since I'm only interested in $Q_1$ and $Q_2$. For this, we can read off one more loop equation for the loop concerning only the capacitors. This is
$$\frac{Q_2}{C_2} + \frac{Q_g}{C_g} - \frac{Q_1}{C_1} = 0, $$
which is the correct expression for the charge conservation. With this, we  yield
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1 (\ddot{Q}_g + \ddot{Q}_1)=\frac{1}{C_1} Q_{1} + L_1\ddot{Q}_1  +  C_g L_1(\frac{\ddot{Q}_1}{C_1} -\frac{\ddot{Q}_2}{C_2} ) = 0\\
       \frac{1}{C_2} Q_2 - L_2(\ddot{Q}_g - \ddot{Q}_2) =\frac{1}{C_2} Q_{2} + L_2\ddot{Q}_2  +  C_g L_2(\frac{\ddot{Q}_2}{C_2} -\frac{\ddot{Q}_1}{C_1} )= 0, 
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}
which can of course be symmetrised a bit by dividing
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{L_1 C_1} Q_{1} + \ddot{Q}_1  +  C_g (\frac{\ddot{Q}_1}{C_1} -\frac{\ddot{Q}_2}{C_2} ) = 0\\
       \frac{1}{C_2 L_2} Q_{2} + \ddot{Q}_2  +  C_g(\frac{\ddot{Q}_2}{C_2} -\frac{\ddot{Q}_1}{C_1} )= 0. 
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}
It will be easier to work with the variable $\Phi_n = Q_n/C_n $ instead so that we can read off the lagrangian easily. With that we have
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{L_1} \Phi_{1} + C_1 \ddot{\Phi}_1  +  C_g(\ddot{\Phi}_1  -\ddot{\Phi}_2  ) = 0\\
       \frac{1}{ L_2} \Phi_{2} + C_2 \ddot{\Phi}_2  +  C_g(\ddot{\Phi}_2  -\ddot{\Phi}_1  )= 0, 
   \end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}
with which we reverse engineer the Lagrangian to be
$$ \mathcal{L}(\Phi_1,\Phi_2;\dot{\Phi}_1,\dot{\Phi}_2) = \frac{C_1}{2}\dot{\Phi}_1^2 -  \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Phi_1^2}{L_1} + \frac{C_2}{2}\dot{\Phi}_2^2 -  \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Phi_2^2}{L_2} + \frac{C_g}{2}\left(\dot{\Phi}_1 - \dot{\Phi}_2 \right)^2, $$
as desired.
Quantasing the problem is now trivial. First, we perform a Legendre transformation to obtain the classical Hamiltonian
$$  \mathcal{H} = \sum_n\left( \dot{\Phi_n} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\Phi_n}}\right)  - \mathcal{L}  =  \frac{C_1}{2}\dot{\Phi}_1^2 +  \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Phi_1^2}{L_1} + \frac{C_2}{2}\dot{\Phi}_2^2 +  \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Phi_2^2}{L_2}  + \frac{C_g}{2}(\dot{\Phi}_1 - \dot{\Phi}_2 )^2$$
which written in terms of canonical conjugates, $ p_n \doteq \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\Phi_n}} = C_n \dot{\Phi}_n $,  is simply
$$  \mathcal{H} =   \frac{1}{2C_1}p_1^2 +  \frac{1}{2}\frac{x_1^2}{L_1} + \frac{1}{2C_2}p_2^2 +  \frac{1}{2}\frac{x_2^2}{L_2}  + \frac{C_g}{2}\left(\frac{p_1}{C_1} - \frac{p_2}{C_2} \right)^2.$$
We could finish here and conclude these are two harmonic oscillators coupled via quadratic terms and call it a day. However, we can simplify the coupling term a bit further by grouping the terms proportional to momentum squared:
$$  \mathcal{H} =   \left(\frac{1}{2C_1} + \frac{C_g}{2C_1^2}\right)p_1^2 +  \frac{1}{2}\frac{x_1^2}{L_1} + \left(\frac{1}{2C_2} + \frac{C_g}{2C_2^2}\right)p_2^2 +  \frac{1}{2}\frac{x_2^2}{L_2}  - C_g\frac{p_1}{C_1} \frac{p_2}{C_2},$$
this was at the expense of making the oscillators dependent on the coupling $C_g$ which isnt necessary. We now define bosonic creation and annihilation operators,
$$ x_n = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda_n}{2}}(a^\dagger_n + a_n), \quad p_n = i\sqrt{\frac{1}{2 \lambda_n}}(a^\dagger_n - a_n), \quad \text{together with} \quad [x,p] = i \iff [a_n, a_n^\dagger]= 1.$$
with all other commutators vanishing, and leave us the freedom to choose $\lambda_n $ wisely. A wise choice for the diagonalisation is $\lambda_n = \sqrt{2L_n \left(\frac{1}{2C_n} + \frac{C_g}{2C_n^2}\right)} $. With this, we have
$$ \mathcal{H} =   \sum_n \sqrt{\frac{1}{L_n}\left(\frac{1}{C_n} + \frac{C_g}{C_n^2}\right)} \left(a^\dagger_n a_n +\frac{1}{2}\right) + \frac{C_g}{2\sqrt{\lambda_1\lambda_2}}\left(a^\dagger_1 - a_1\right)\left(a^\dagger_2 - a_2\right).$$
It is clear in the limit $C_g=0$ this reduces to two independent LC oscillators.
